# In the way i understood vs In the way as i understood

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, phrases

I am really confused about these 2 phrases

> - In the way i understood
> - in the way as i understood

I ve got this confusion from an email, which has been sent by one of my friends,and the full sentence was like

> so i just gave (out) an answer to that question in the way as i understood.`

*AS* is the real problem here

Wha is the difference between

> In the way i understood

and

> in the way as i understood??

Comment: Yes, it is - your friend should have omitted it.

Comment: could you please explain the difference??

Comment: Simply that the version with _as_ is wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conjunction "as" doesn't seem to make sense here. The author probably wants the following clause to modify "the way". The most common way to do that would be with a relative clause:

> I just gave (out) an answer to that question in the way in which I understood it.<sup>1</sup>

However, we often leave out "in which" after "way" (as I did in my previous sentence):

> I just gave (out) an answer to that question in the way I understood it.

There's still one more issue, though: I don't think that "in" is the correct preposition there. Most people would certainly understand this sentence as it was intended, but I think that this makes more sense:

> I just gave (out) an answer to that question according to the way I understood it.

---

<sup>1</sup>I fixed some other minor issues with the sentence.